# MD5 to hash generating the same hash code

Tags: c#, hash, md5, filestream

I'm setting up a Blob, and I need to get some stuff to insert them in my database, so I made a code to get an hashId based on my Stream

I have already tried to use IFormFile at me FileStorageService, but this is a little bit wrong.

```
private string GetMD5HashFromFile(Stream data)
       {
          using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
          {
            using (var fileStream = data)
              {

                  var hash = md5.ComputeHash(fileStream);

                  var hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

                  return hashString.TrimEnd('=');

              }

          }
       }
```

This code is always generating the same hash, and in this way, I can't save my Blob information on my database

Comment: Maybe you want to hash the content of the file and not the FileStream object?

Comment: Did you ensure that the `Position` of the stream is 0 upon entering this method?

Comment: @churill `MD5.ComputeHash` has an overload accepting a `Stream`.

Comment: @churill I believe that I need to hash all the stream, but if you have a solution, I'll accept

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Is there a way to verify that? because the first time that I'm generating the hash, it comes to me something.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the contents of the Streams is different? If you change the code to 
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(Enumerable.Range(0, 16).Select(x => (byte)fileStream.ReadByte()).ToArray()).TrimEnd('='); does it still give you the same values?

Comment: @SeanReid I'll try

Comment: To check you're at the start of the stream, try doing fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); Depending on the type of stream, seeking may not be supported though.

Comment: @SeanReid I tried to get the return, and get this /////////////////////w

Comment: Well that's the content of the stream. If it's always the same, your streams have the same content, and they'll always have the same MD5 hash.

Comment: @SeanReid Interesting, I'll check better my method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on C.Evenhuis comment, a friend of mine resolve in this way:

```
 private string GetMD5HashFromFile(Stream data)
        {
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                data.Position = 0;
                var hash = md5.ComputeHash(data);
                var hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

                return hashString.TrimEnd('=');

            }
        }
```